# Restkit multipartFormRequestForObject example does not build for me

Tags: restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

My viewController has the following method, which gets called after an image gets selected via a UIImagePickerController.  I'd like to upload the selected image to my web service, however, when attempting to follow the samples provided by RestKit I get the following error:

No visible @interface for 'RKObjectManager' declares the selector 'multipartFormRequestForObject:method:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:'

I'm using the most recent version of restkit, and right clicked went to definition to check the signature which seems correct.

It is worth noting that AFMultipartFormData is not highlighting in XCode.  I tried including #import AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h but it still shows as plain text, which i suspect might be the problem?

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    ImageRecord *imageRecord = [ImageRecord new];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"param1" : @"value1",
                             @"param2" : @"value2",
                             @"param3" : @"value3"};

    // Serialize the Article attributes then attach a file
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestForObject:imageRecord method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"stuff" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                    name:@"article[image]"
                                fileName:@"photo.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation]; // NOTE: Must be enqueued rather than started


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is `multipartFormRequestWithObject:` (note that the method name you're using has `ForObject`). You shouldn't need to import any additional headers.

Comment: You rock!  I copy pasted the code from RestKit's github, so I never suspected something like that.  Thanks for saving me loads of time again Wain.